# Post request curl

Tags: curl, php, http, post

Выполняю авторизацию курлом. Подскажите, как проверить какой код состояния пришел? Т. е. если приходит

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found {
    echo $message;
}
```

Если приходит

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK {
    echo $error;
}
```

Comment: @Vasja Pupkin, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Используй функцию `get_headers`

Comment: попытался,как-то не очень вышло,можно пример?

Comment: <?php
        $headers = get_headers("http://ya.ru");
        echo $headers[0]; // HTTP/1.1 200 Ok

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [curl_getinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-getinfo.php)

```
<?php
        $ch = curl_init('http://ya.ru');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_exec($ch);
        $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) . "\n";
        curl_close($ch);
```